# piping stockfish misbehaves in fedora

Tags: c++, pipe, virtual-machine, fedora

Somewhere in my project I use fork and pipe to execute another process and pipe its I/O to communicate with it (I'm writing it in C++). There is no problem when I compile it in Ubuntu 14.04, it will work just fine, but I compiled it in fedora on a WMWare virtual machine and strange things began to happen. If I run the binary in terminal, there is no error but nothing will be written in the pipe (but getting streams of characters will work). I tried to debug my code in fedora, I put a break point in my code, but then a broken pipe signal was given when process tried to read from pipe (there were no signals when executing in terminal).
So, have any of you encountered such problems before? Is there any difference in piping between debian and red hat linux? Or is it because I'm running fedora on a virtual machine?

CODE:

```
int mFD_p2c [2];
int mFD_c2p [2];
int mEnginePID;

if (pipe(mFD_p2c) != 0 || pipe(mFD_c2p) != 0)
{
  cout << "Failed to pipe";
  exit(1);
}
mEnginePID = fork();

if (mEnginePID < 0)
{
  cout << "Fork failed";
  exit(-1);
}
else if (mEnginePID == 0)
{
  if (dup2(mFD_p2c[0], 0) != 0 ||
      close(mFD_p2c[0]) != 0 ||
      close(mFD_p2c[1]) != 0)
  {
     cout << "Child: failed to set up standard input";
     exit(1);
  }
  if (dup2(mFD_c2p[1], 1) != 1 ||
      close(mFD_c2p[1]) != 0 ||
      close(mFD_c2p[0]) != 0)
  {
     cout << "Child: failed to set up standard output";
     exit(1);
  }

  string engine = "stockfish";
  execlp(engine.c_str(), (char *) 0);
  cout << "Failed to execute " << engine;
  exit(1);
}
else
{
  close(mFD_p2c[0]);
  close(mFD_c2p[1]);

  string str = "uci";
  int nbytes = str.length();
  if (write(mFD_p2c[1], str.c_str(), nbytes) != nbytes)
  {
     cout << "Parent: short write to child";
     exit(1);
  }

  cout << "The following string has been written to engine:\n"
       << string(1, '\t') << str;

  char readBuffer[2];
  string output = "";

  while (1)
  {
     int bytes_read = read(mFD_c2p[0], readBuffer, sizeof(char));

     if (readBuffer[0] == '\n')
        break;

     readBuffer[bytes_read] = '\0';

     output += readBuffer;
  }

  cout << "Got: " << output;
}
```

Comment: You are not going to get much help with this request. There is not enough detail for people to do more than guess and guessed answers are discouraged. You need to simplify your code to the smallest possible code that exhibits the problem and paste it here.

Comment: There are no differences in piping between debian and red hat linux. Probably you just have an error in your code. Don't use debugger when you are working with pipes. debugger sends signal to interrupt the process on breakpoint and it breaks the pipe. You can try to add printf() functions to your code to print debug information.

Comment: @LokiAstari Alright I added a minimum code to give you the details of  piping in my code

Comment: Your minimum code will not compile, or possibly work on either Fedora or Ubuntu. This is because your code takes the number of characters in str before it actually declares this variable.

Comment: @Sandro alright, but the exact code runs on ubuntu just fine. Actually I tried writing to std::out for debugging too, everything is good and no error is thrown, but nothing will be written in pipe or maybe it will be written but not completely, because the forked process will react to '\n' character but it says that it does not recognizes the command given (see the code above which I updated)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Dude, of course it will not compile! its just an structure to give you the idea, I should upload my whole project for you if you want to compile it!

Comment: @sinaTavakoli No, what you should do is replace "stockfish" with something ubiquitous and add boilerplate so that it does compile.

Comment: @PSkocik Does it really matter what "stockfish" is? assume that its a process (any process). Replace it with "top" if you really want it to be compiled.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Here, I swapped those two lines to make you happy :)

Comment: After quick look to the code I can advice to check the bytes_read variable value. Maybe read() returns an error. And you should add to "output" string only bytes_read number of chars, not whole readBuffer

Comment: @Sandro good point, but the if continued after reading bytes will check this (errors will return values lesser or equal to 0) and as I said there is no problem in reading from the pipe but writing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using Stockfish. I too have exactly experienced this behavior from Stockfish. The problem lies within how it handles output. Defined in `misc.h`:

```
#define sync_cout std::cout << IO_LOCK
```

And looking at the code again we'll see that `IO_LOCK` is an enum which is used in an overloaded friend operator for cout:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SyncCout sc) {

  static Mutex m;

  if (sc == IO_LOCK)
      m.lock();

  if (sc == IO_UNLOCK)
      m.unlock();

  return os;
}
```

What I see here is that during using cout, a mutex is locked. I don't know how exactly this affects cout's output in a pipe instead of stdout, but I'm positive that this is the cause for the problem. You can check it by removing the lock functionality.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that the pipe behavior is not different in linux based systems as mentioned before, but there might be slight differences between distributions handling mutexes used with pipes.

Comment: Wow, nice answer man! Yea I can confirm this as I changed the chess engine (the other one didn't have mutex locks and things) and there were no problem there. I don't have any idea why this is working on ubuntu but not fedora, maybe I'll check what you guessed, to see if removing mutex will solve it or not. But does distributions really affect handling the mutexes? Hm...

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences in piping between debian and red hat, but the following list of questions may help you:

-Are the Ubuntu and the Fedora using the same architecture (64 bit vs 32) ?

-Are you using the same version of gcc (or any other compiler) ?

(Suggestion: use cerr for your error outputs, and maybe your debug output too -> you dup the standard outputs and inputs, so if something fails you may not see it)

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, here's how you turn it into a self-contained, compilable example:

**stockfish**

```
#cat stockfish 
tr a-z A-Z #just so we do something
echo       #need to end with a "\n" or else the parent won't break out of the while loop
```

**Run command:**

```
make pipes && PATH=.:$PATH pipes
```

**pipes.cc**

```
//pipes.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    using namespace std;
  int mFD_p2c [2];
  int mFD_c2p [2];
  int mEnginePID;

  if (pipe(mFD_p2c) != 0 || pipe(mFD_c2p) != 0)
  {
    cout << "Failed to pipe";
    exit(1);
  }
  mEnginePID = fork();

  if (mEnginePID < 0)
  {
    cout << "Fork failed";
    exit(-1);
  }
  else if (mEnginePID == 0)
  {
    if (dup2(mFD_p2c[0], 0) != 0 ||
        close(mFD_p2c[0]) != 0 ||
        close(mFD_p2c[1]) != 0)
    {
      cout << "Child: failed to set up standard input";
      exit(1);
    }
    if (dup2(mFD_c2p[1], 1) != 1 ||
        close(mFD_c2p[1]) != 0 ||
        close(mFD_c2p[0]) != 0)
    {
      cout << "Child: failed to set up standard output";
      exit(1);
    }

    string engine = "stockfish";
    char *const args[]={};
    int ret;
    execvp(engine.c_str(), args);
    //I need the endl here or else it doesn't show for me when the execvp fails; I wasn't able to compile the original exec command so I used a different one from the exec* family
    cout << "Failed to execute " << engine << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
    close(mFD_p2c[0]);
    close(mFD_c2p[1]);

    string str = "uci";
    int nbytes = str.length();
    if (write(mFD_p2c[1], str.c_str(), nbytes) != nbytes)
    {
      cout << "Parent: short write to child";
      exit(1);
    }
    //My particular child process tries to read to the end, so give it the EOF
    close(mFD_p2c[1]);

    cout << "The following string has been written to engine:\n"
      << string(1, '\t') << str;

    char readBuffer[2];
    string output = "";

    while (1)
    {
      int bytes_read = read(mFD_c2p[0], readBuffer, sizeof(char));

      if (readBuffer[0] == '\n')
        break;

      readBuffer[bytes_read] = '\0';

      output += readBuffer;
    }

    cout << "Got: " << output;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
The following string has been written to engine:
        uciGot: UCI
```

Comment: Wut? What? Why? This would make pipes almost unusable. The man 7 pipe states : `If  a  process  attempts  to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will
       block until data is available.  If a process attempts  to  write  to  a
       full  pipe  (see below), then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has
       been read from the pipe to allow the write  to  complete.`. So it seems you kinda took it the other way around...

Comment: @zoska You're right. I made up a stupid, wrong explanation for why I needed to at the close call. I guess I needed that close because my particular child process was trying to read till the end. It would have worked if it just tried to read 3 characters. Thanks for the comment.